# Bad status request on Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

Bad status for request 37563: TGetOperationStatusResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=None, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, infoMessages=None, statusCode=0), operationState=5, errorMessage=None, sqlState=None, errorCode=None)

I am facing this when i tried to run the following query.

```
refresh sst_spot_quotes;
select
  case
    when maxrecordforSST >= hours_sub (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 4) then ''
    else 'error'
  end as msg
from
  (
    select
      to_timestamp (
        CONCAT (
          max(rdate),
          MAX(
            CONCAT (
              LPAD (CAST(rhour as STRING), 2, '0'),
              ':',
              LPAD (CAST(rminute as STRING), 2, '0'),
              ':',
              LPAD (CAST(rsecond as STRING), 2, '0')
            )
          )
        ),
        'yyyy-mmm-ddhh:mm:ss'
      ) as maxrecordforSST
    from
      sst_spot_quotes
    where
      rdate >= days_sub (to_date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), 1)
  ) a
```

Could someone help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The date format must be `yyyy-MMM-ddhh:mm:ss`.  Pls note i made MMM as uppercase.
Could you please change and try?

Also, its not a good idea to get the max and then to_timestamp but reverse. Because calculating max on date will give correct maximum date than string.

You can give below SQL a try.

```
select
  case
    when maxrecordforSST >= hours_sub (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 4) then ''
    else 'error'
  end as msg
from
  (
    select
      MAX(to_timestamp (
        CONCAT (
          (rdate),
          (
            CONCAT (
              LPAD (CAST(rhour as STRING), 2, '0'),
              ':',
              LPAD (CAST(rminute as STRING), 2, '0'),
              ':',
              LPAD (CAST(rsecond as STRING), 2, '0')
            )
          )
        ),
        'yyyy-MMM-ddhh:mm:ss'
      )) as maxrecordforSST
    from
      sst_spot_quotes
    where
      rdate >= days_sub (to_date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), 1)
  ) a
```

Comment: Hi Koushik, Even your query is also throwing me the same error. The data format also is wrong from your query.

Comment: can you pls post some sample data and table structure? There can be issue in the data or in structure.